# How do I rotate or translate individual object instances in OPENGL?

Tags: opengl

Lets say i have a scene with four cubes. How do I say rotate/translate only two of these cubes in OpenGL without changing the others using glrotatef anf gltranslate? I dont wanna define my own homogeneous co-ordinates.

Comment: Did you look into glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() ?

Answer (score 5):

1. You draw your first two cubes as usual
2. Push the view-model matrix (`glPushMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)`)
3. Call glRotate/glTranslate to setup the rotation of the two cubes which you want to draw in a different way
4. Draw the other two cubes
5. Pop the original view-model matrix (`glPopMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)`)

Comment: Agreed, except that glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix don't take a parameter.  They work on whichever matrix stack is current (based on glMatrixMode).