# Move position of mesh in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have a world with some polygons (shapeRenderer) and want to have an arrow which moves when the user changes his GPS position. i thought i could do it with meshes, but i didn't find any option to move the mesh to another position.

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 6, 0, 
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 2, "a_position")
);
mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.3f, -0.3f,
            0   , 0,
            0f  , 0.7f,
            0   , 0,
            0.3f, -0.3f,
            0f  , 0.7f  });
mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6);
```

Is there a option to change the position of the whole mesh? or can i get all of the vertices to create an new mesh with the new position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) a couple ways to "move" a mesh.  There is no specific support in Libgdx for this, its just the same options any OpenGL app has:

1. Change the vertices
2. Use a translation matrix
3. Render the mesh to a texture and move the texture around

To **change the vertices** you will have to keep track of the `float[]` and mutate it (or re-create it) when you want to "move" the mesh.  You can invoke `setVertices` again with the new data.

For the **translation matrix** approach see [How do I rotate or translate individual object instances in OPENGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875376/how-do-i-rotate-or-translate-individual-object-instances-in-opengl)  However, note that this is mostly deprecated with more recent OpenGL APIs.  (I'm not entirely clear with what they replaced it with, though: I think you're supposed to do the matrix math on your own, which is basically option #1.)

For the **render to texture** option, use a [Libgdx `FrameBuffer` object](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html), render to that, then use a [Libgdx `Sprite`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) to move/render that texture.  Note that the `Sprite` implementation is just built on a simple quad of vertices and is effectively [doing option #1](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L201) to move the sprite around the screen, so this option makes sense only if your mesh is really complicated and has lots and lots of vertices.

Hmm... Now that I've written that out, it looks like all three boil down to option 1: you should track the actual location in the mesh vertices yourself.

Comment: i tried to change the vertices, but there is one problem. i want to calibrate the arrow to the position where the user look at. i did that with `gl.glRotatef(360-(Gdx.input.getAzimuth()), 0, 0, 0.1f);`
but when i add i.e. to all of the x-values +0.001f and let it rotate around `0,0.001f, 0.1f)` it rotates in a big radius

Comment: it rotates around (0,0,0) with `gl.glRotatef(360-(Gdx.input.getAzimuth()), 0, 0.001f, 0.1f);` but i want it rotate it around (0, 0.001f, 0). When i set z to 0 it isn't visible anymore

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but what I do is

```
mesh.transform(matrix);
mesh.render();
mesh.transform(matrix.inv());
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing explanation rather than just code.

Comment: Holy shitballs man! Thank god for this! I have searched everywhere for doing mesh transformations in modern OpenGL and this is it right here! Thank you!