# OpenGL object not rotating

Tags: opengl, cross-platform, glut, glrotate

So, I've been trying to rotate a single object in an OpenGL/GLUT environment. 
[After](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515059/how-to-rotate-a-specific-object-in-opengl)  going through several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875376/how-do-i-rotate-or-translate-individual-object-instances-in-opengl) on SO and the like, I've written what appears to be correct code, but no dice. Does anyone know how to make this work?

PS: I've tried changing the GLMatrixmode to Projection, but that just shows a black screen. Same thing happens if I use glLoadIdentity().
Here's my rendering code

```
void display()
{
    preProcessEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(Camera::position.x, Camera::position.y, Camera::position.z,
              Camera::position.x+Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.x)*Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.y),
              Camera::position.y+Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.x),
              Camera::position.z+Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.x)*Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.y),
              0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 0,-3);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 2.0f,-3);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f,-3);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->textureID);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(100, 100);
    glVertex3f(100,0,100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100, 100);
    glVertex3f(-100,0,100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100,-100);
    glVertex3f(-100,0,-100);

    glTexCoord2f(100,-100);
    glVertex3f(100,0,-100);

    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    object1.draw();

    glTranslatef(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2->textureID);
    gluQuadricTexture(quad,1);
    gluSphere(quad,10,20,20);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
//RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(190, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware what `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` do? They save and restore the *"current"* matrix.

By enclosing your rotation in that and then doing no actual drawing operation before restoring the matrix the entire sequence of code beginning with `//RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE` is completely pointless.

Even if you did not push/pop, your rotation would only be applied the ***next*** time you draw something. Logically you might think that would mean the next time you call `display (...)`, but one of the first things you do in `display (...)` is replace the current matrix with an identity matrix (line 3).

In all honesty, you should consider abandoning whatever resource you are currently using to learn OpenGL. You are using deprecated functionality and missing a few fundamentals. A good OpenGL 3.0 tutorial will usually touch on the basics of transformation matrices.

---

As for why changing the matrix mode to projection produces a black screen, that is because the next time you call `display (...)`, `gluLookAt` operates on the projection matrix. In effect, you wind up applying the camera transformation twice. You should really add `glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)` to the beginning of `display (...)` to avoid this.

Comment: oops. I just realised how I'd used glRotate after drawing the sphere. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. As for the deprecated functions, my professor is a dinosaur and he'll only let me use old versions of OpenGL

Answer (score 1):

You do the rotation (and reset it with glPopMatrix) *after* you draw, do the rotation code before the glBegin/glEnd calls.

Or just move to the shader based pipeline and manage you own transformation matrices.